# Custom modules with CDN

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using Esri's ArcGis CDN and I want to have some custom modules. My directory structure is as follows

```
Scripts
    app
        basemap.js
        test.js
Views
    Maps
        General.cshtml
```

In `General.html` I have this for my dojo config

```
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1, dojoBlankHtmlUrl: '/blank.html',
    packages: [ {
        name: 'app',
        //Can't configure location correctly
        location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + ''
    } ]"
src="//js.arcgis.com/3.7/"></script>
```

Testing usage in test.js

```
require([
   "dojo/ready",
   "app/basemap"
], function (ready, basemap) {

    basemap.test();

}
```

If I use an absolute path `location: 'http://localhost:53862/Scripts/app'` then it works fine.

I've tried a few other things for `''` but I can't seem to navigate from the `Maps` folder across to my `app` folder. All the examples I looked at either specify a subdirectory for the location or an absolute path. Is there I way I can do something like `../Scripts/app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my dojoconfig to the following

```
<script data-dojo-config="
    packages: [ {
        name: 'app',
        location: '//' + window.location.host + '/Scripts/app'
    } ]"
src="//js.arcgis.com/3.7/"></script>
```

Which set my `app` package to `http://localhost:53862/Scripts/app`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read ["Configuring Dojo with dojoConfig"](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/) and ["Using Custom Modules with a CDN"](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/cdn/).

Eg Google CDN.

*dojo config, look at property baseUrl*

```
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1,
               dojoBlankHtmlUrl: '/blank.html',
               baseUrl: '/Scripts',
               packages:[
               { name:'dojo',location:'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/'},
              { name:'app',location:location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + 'app'}]"
            src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js">
</script>
```

*after, test your custom module*

```
require([
   "dojo/ready",
   "app/basemap"
], function (ready, basemap) {

    basemap.test();

}
```

Comment: baseUrl will specify the base url for all packages though, meaning it will try to look for the dojo stuff under `/Scripts`.